# How does niceness relate to CPU allocation on Solaris?

Tags: cpu, solaris, parallel-processing

The [wikipedia article for nice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_%28Unix%29) describes the relationship as follows:

> As a simple example, when two otherwise identical CPU-bound processes are running simultaneously on a single-CPU Linux system, each one's share of the CPU time will be proportional to 20−p, where p is the process' priority. Thus a process run with nice +15 will receive 25% of the CPU time allocated to a normal-priority process: (20−15)/(20−0) = 0.25. On the BSD 4.x scheduler, on the other hand, the ratio in the same example is about ten to one.

I would like to know how the CPU share allocated to each process in the above simple example would be calculated on a Solaris server, including the case where one process has nice +19. Bonus points if you can provide a link to any documentation that covers this for SunOS 5.1.

Edit: I have also requested citations for the scheduler behaviour described in the wikipedia entry.

Comment: SunOS 5.1 (aka Solaris 2.1) from 1992?  or SunOS 5.10 (aka Solaris 10) from 2005?

Comment: The latter- apologies for the ambguity.